# URL to web clustered application in WebLogic

Tags: url, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x

I have deployed a WebLogic Cluster in WL 10.3, with EJBs and JMS. There are one admin server and two managed nodes.

I have a Web Application in a .war file, so it has been deployed on the managed nodes by "all the cluster nodes" option.

I access to the application in each node, with URLs: http://localhost:7101/myApp and httop://localhost:7201/myApp. They work.

So, my question is: how can I configure a single URL (http://localhost:8000/myApp or something like that) to make the cluster transparent for the final user? In this way, the user writes http://calhost:8000/myApp and there is something that maps the two nodes, makes load balancing, etc., but transparent for the user.

Thanks in advance. Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a load balancer, you can get the load balancer to do this. But I don't think this is what you were looking for.

There are two other options:

- Use [Apache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/plugins/apache.html) or a supported web server (that can act as a load balancer). Apache can be configured to perform load balancing across multiple WebLogic nodes in a cluster. You'll need to install the mod_weblogic plugin.
- Create and configure a [HTTP Proxy application for the cluster](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/common/docs103/confgwiz/custom.html#wp1055774), that will act as the intermediary node in the cluster for requests to other nodes in the cluster.

The approach of using the HTTP proxy application is less recommended, but could be considered if you do not want to put a dedicated load balancer, or a web server that proxies requests to the cluster.

Comment: your HTTP Proxy solution has worked for me. Apache is not installed, it seems a better solution than the proxy, but now this is the one I need and it works. Thanks a lot, Vineet